# Cant load custom fonts in nextjs using material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

I have been trying to load custom fonts for my NextJS project into material ui but the build errors out with this

```
error - ./public/fonts/Proxima-Nova-Black.otf
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '' (1:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
```

I have been trying to modify `next.config` to have the fonts load up but nothing seems to be working. Does anybody have any idea what I can do next?

Here's my code for MUI `theme.ts`

```
import { createTheme } from '@mui/material';
import proximaRegular from './public/fonts/Proxima-Nova.ttf';
import proximaBlack from './public/fonts/Proxima-Nova-Black.otf';
import proximaSBold from './public/fonts/Proxima-Nova-SBold.ttf';

const theme = createTheme({
  typography: {
    fontFamily: 'ProximaRegular, ProximaBlack, ProximaSBold, Arial, Roboto',
  },
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: '#FFD600',
    },
  },
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
              @font-face {
          font-family: 'ProximaRegular';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${proximaRegular}) format('ttf');
          unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'ProximaBlack';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${proximaBlack}) format('otf');
          unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }

        @font-face {
          font-family: 'ProximaSBold';
          font-style: normal;
          font-display: swap;
          font-weight: 400;
          src: url(${proximaSBold}) format('ttf');
          unicodeRange: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF;
        }
      `,
    },
  },
});

export default theme;
```

and I have integrated this theme inside my nextjs app using `themeprovider`